# How to list all Linux environment variables including LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

How to list all the environment variables in Linux?

When I type the command `env` or `printenv` it gives me lots of variables, but some variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG` don't show up in this list.

I want to type a command that list all the environment variables including this variables (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG`)

Comment: Why do you think that those should have values?

Comment: Because I add values to them

Comment: If they don't show up, then not correctly.

Comment: The GNU standards recommend installing by default all libraries in /usr/local/lib....

Comment: You may also want to read this first: http://www.cc.dtu.dk/?page_id=304

Comment: `set`, `typeset` and `export` come to mind. Read `man bash` for more information on what they do and what options you can give them to narrow down what you're looking for...

Comment: If you've assigned a value to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but not `export`ed it, then it has no effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`env` does list all environment variables.

If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not there, then that variable was not declared; or was declared but not `export`ed, so that child processes do not inherit it.

If you are setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your shell start-up files, like `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` make sure it is exported:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 12):

try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

This will modify the variable.

To print it, type: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it should show the above value.

If you're seeing nothing when you print that, then the variable might not be set.

Answer (score 2):

The question in fact is a good question. when run `env` or `printenv`, the output will be the system environment, but LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not belong to.

For example, if you set `a=1`, you can't show it by `env`. Same as LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it is used by ld.so only(ld. so – this little program that starts all your applications)